# How can I implement jquery dataTabel in asp.net NOT MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

These are the steps I use:

1. List item create data base.
2. create asp.net web application.
3. add to web application linq to sql to retreive data from DB.
4. how can I implement this data in jqueryTable.

Comment: What do you mean by ASP.NET not MVC? Specifically what framework are you using?

Comment: MVC is a framework for developing web applications on top of Asp.Net, so your question doesn't make much sense. Do you mean to use webforms (.aspx) without MVC ?

Comment: yes this is what i mean webforms (.aspx) without mvc.@mason @derloopkat

Comment: Why can't you add Web API and/or MVC to your existing ASP.NET app that uses Web Forms?

Comment: This is a task from my supervisor 

Comment: Then you supervisor has given unclear instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api) controller in standard ASP.NET. Or, if you are using .NET Core, you can use the more [generic controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Then, you can access your data via an ajax request and display the data however you like in your [jQuery data table](https://datatables.net/). Hope that helps.